# New line in FileOutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

Ascii value of next line is 10. so i tried this...

```
 FileOutputStream os = new  FileOutputStream(f, true);
    os.write(10);  // this should get me to next line ?
    os.write(b);   // b is a byte array...
```

Comment: its not working, the next lne is not there instead it appends from the last character in the file

Answer (score 6):

You should take care of managing crossplatform line separator, this can be retrieved in many ways:

- `System.getProperty("line.separator")`
- `System.lineSeparator()` (only Java7)
- `String.format("%n")`

Then you should take care of using a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around your `FileOutputStream`, this because you will be allowed to choose many better methods like

- `writeChars(String str)`
- `writeBytes(String str)`
- `writeUTF(String str)`

so that you will use the most suitable for your situation.

Mind also that writing a byte array directly on the stream creates binary data, which is somewhat opposite to using newlines (which are text instead).

Comment: Sir, this i know that if i wrap around with bufferedoutputstream or Dataoutputstream, i can easily go to next line... just wanted to know that if os.write(32);//space is working then why not  10*

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

On windows you need to use 13 and 10 as line separator (CR, LF) - i.e.:

```
os.write(13);
os.write(10);
```

Hence, if you want your app to be platform independent, you should use whatever is in the line.separator system property as Jack suggests.